# Different longitude coming from Google place details API and Google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have noticed that in almost every test I have done.

From one side, I am use the Google places API to get the coordinates of place, ex

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=EjVLaWZpc2lhcyA2NiwgQXRoaW5hLCBLZW50cmlrb3MgVG9tZWFzIEF0aGlub24sIEdyZWVjZQ&key=[API_KEY]

the above result gives

[image: Place from Google Place API]

On the other situation where I enter the address in Google maps on a browser I get the following result

[image: Place from Google maps]

So, the latitude is the same in each situation but the longitude is different? Could it be something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "@" coordinates are not the location of the place searched for, they are the center of the map.

Statue of Liberty search result on Google Maps:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Statue+of+Liberty+National+Monument/@40.6892494,-74.0466891,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c25090129c363d:0x40c6a5770d25022b!8m2!3d40.6892494!4d-74.0445004

Places API result:

```
{
  "formatted_address": "New York, NY, United States",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 40.6892494,
      "lng": -74.0445004
    },
    "viewport": {
      "south": 40.6795946,
      "west": -74.06026579999997,
      "north": 40.7182138,
      "east": -73.9972042
    }
  },
  "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_recreational-71.png",
  "id": "5a0d7e67078e35af0c456a277df9ffba7c1e4da6",
  "name": "Statue of Liberty National Monument",
```

What's here (right click) result on Google Maps (clicking on the icon):

> Statue of Liberty National Monument
>
> New York, NY
>
> 40.689253, -74.044479

(the [answer from google on "Get the coordinates of a place"](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539), says to do the right click:

> **Get the coordinates of a place**
>
> To find the coordinates of a place on Google Maps, follow the steps below.
>
> 1. Open Google Maps.
> 2. Right-click the place or area on the map.
> 3. Select What's here?
> 4. A card appears at the bottom of the screen with more info.
>
> Note: If you're using Maps in Lite mode, you won't be able to get the coordinates of a place.